# button added to UITableViewController net getting set in front of tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm programatically adding a button to a UITableViewController like this:

```
-(void)createFlipButton
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(282, 372, 18, 19);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
}
```

But it's getting stuck in the cell that occupies the button.frame space. why isn't  `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button]` working?

Also,  `[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:button]` doesn't work either.

Comment: Where do u want the button to be added? top of tableView or within a cell of tableView?

Comment: What does "But it's getting stuck in the cell that occupies the button.frame space." mean?

Comment: Where do you call createFlipButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* what you really want is a **floating view**, i.e. a view that doesn't move when the table view scrolls. The reason the button looks sticky to your cell is that the whole table is in a scroll view, so when the content moves, the button does as well.

The way to go is to adjust the position of your added view when the table scrolls. Just implement the delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     CGPoint buttonOrigin = CGPointMake(200,50);
     self.button.frame = CGRectMake(buttonOrigin.x, buttonOrigin.y + self.tableView.bounds.origin.y, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);
}
```

You will need to store a reference for your button, so that you can access it here, and maybe put the location of the button into an ivar as well.

If you have access to the WWDC 2011 Videos, you will find the trick there in Session 125.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent UIView; Add your button to that UIView, and then add that UIView to the view hierarchy you have.
This should work as per what you asked (button not be part of table view).
Put comments below if any help with the sample code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to use Table View and other UI items in a same view, I use UIViewController. This view controller conforms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. The UITableView delegate and DataSource methods are implemented and thus this view controller also work as the Table view controller. I use IB or story boards to make connections. But this should also work if you want to create everything programmatically.

In your case, if you want the UIButton to be separate from the table view, using a UIViewController as described above is one of the options.

Answer (score -1):

The you should add the button within the tableHeaderView

```
-(void)createFlipButton
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 18, 19);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = button
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



and implement the following UITableView Delegate
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section   {

return 44;/// sample
}
```

Comment: not over top as in the header view. I want it where my frame above says. Just not part of the tableView

Comment: try converting the base class to UIViewController instead of UITableViewController i.e in the interface (.h) file and do the required changes in the corresponding XIB file

Comment: that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

Button add on **UItableViewCell**

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:Button];
```